# Can I filter the Users returned by GetAllUsers based on a role they are in

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to create an administration interface where users and roles (among other things) can be administered. I have a list of users who can be edited, deleted or viewed. I have this code in the action:

```
var model = Membership.GetAllUsers()
   .Cast<MembershipUser>()
   .Select(x => new UserModel
      {
       UserName = x.UserName,
       Email = x.Email,
       UserRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(x.UserName)
      });

return View(model);
```

This is all fine except that I don't want admins to be able to edit each other. So I need to filter out all users in the "super admin" role. I can certainly figure this out by stepping through each role for each user to see if they are a member. I am wondering if there is a nice sucinct way to do this by filtering the result set in the Select statement, or using Except or Where

Answer (score 0):

I would normally think about the sql I want generated then try write the linq, filtering by roles should be fairly easy with a simple where statement.

However it appears you're trying to abstract each part of the query into smaller bits, this may make it easier to write but can have a devastating effect on performance.  For example, I wouldn't be suprised if the GetRolesForUser method you are calling causing an extra database query per user that is returned by GetAllUsers, using the Include method is a much nicer way to get all roles at the same time.

```
var model = context.Users
           .Include(user => user.UserRoles)
           .Where(user => !user.UserRoles.Any(role => role == superAdmin)
           .Select(user => new UserModel() { UserName = user.UserName, Email = user.Email, UserRoles = user.UserRoles});
```